# local wordpress can't set picture in post

Tags: wordpress, mamp, media-library

I set up a wordpress installation locally on my Mac running MAMP (default, not pro). Front- and backend working as expected, but I can't set a image to a post.

Issue: When I open the Media library by the "add Media" button in the post editor, the library keeps loading (first picture).
But when I navigate to "Media" the pictures are shown (second picture). Uploading pictures works **only** in the Media panel opened from the sidebar. When try to upload a picture from a post (aka "add Media" Button) will fail.

Maybe important(?): when I open the media library FireBug shows a warning related to scroll-linked effects (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Scroll-linked_effects). Chrome's console keeps blank.

What I tried: set up wordpress twice, changed recursively the permissions of the content directory. Still not working, not in Chrome, not in the FF.

What's going wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

#### MEDIA LIB (OPENED FROM POST)

[image: shows loading]

---

---

#### MEDIA LIB (SIDEBAR)

[image: this works]

Answer (score 0):

Same installation with XAMPP -> fully working.